# Redeploy web application on Tomcat through Maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have installed and deployed a web application on Linux server using Tomcat and the following commmands:

```
 mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true

 mvn tomcat:run -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8081 & > log.txt
```

I've changed the tomcat > web.xml that exists inside my project folder and in order for the modification to be activated I need to restart server or re-deploy the web application?
What command do I need to restart this tomcat instance?
I tried this

```
 mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true tomcat:redeploy
```

but it returned the error:

```
 Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Error writing to server
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the tomcat manager webapp into your tomcat instance?

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_using_the_Tomcat_Manager

It's not installed by default.  Also maven isn't normally used to restart the tomcat server, only redeploy applications...

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

Edit tomcat conf/server.xml add your project context(upto application webaaps dir)
or add a seperate context in tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost
For eg:- create a file text.xml and add following entires in it.

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context reloadable="true" docBase="D:\myfolder\WORK_SPACE\application\src\main\webapp">
    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

    <Manager debug="0" className="org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager" saveOnRestart="true">
        <Store className="org.apache.catalina.session.FileStore"/>
    </Manager>

</Context>
```

Edit project path accordingly.Copy this file in tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost and
Execute maven command, mvn clean compile war:inplace.

Restart tomcat and access you app like

eg: ip:port/test . test is the name of context added in local host folder..in our case test.xml    `